# Error: failed to get recent blockhash: FetchError: request to http://localhost:8899/ failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:8899

Tags: anchor-lang, local-cluster

I am not sure what is the reason behind this error i get this error at random. I have set the anchor.toml file to localnet

Comment: Hm, this would point to some local setup issues, perhaps the validator going down in the middle of a test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few possible answer's to this problem can be the Node Version you are using. It seams to work with node v16 sometimes. I still haven't got it working with anchor localnet but the solana-test-validator works fine.